# reading google bucket data in spark

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have followed this blog to read data stored in google bucket. https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/connectors/install-storage-connector
It has worked fine. The following command

`hadoop fs -ls gs://the-bucket-you-want-to-list`

gave me expected results.But when I tried reading data using pyspark using

`rdd = sc.textFile("gs://crawl_tld_bucket/")`,

it throws the following error:

`

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o20.partitions.
: java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: gs
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
`
```

How to get it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access Google Cloud Storage you have to include Cloud Storage connector:

```
spark-submit --jars /path/to/gcs/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar your-pyspark-script.py
```

or

```
pyspark --jars /path/to/gcs/gcs-connector-latest-hadoop2.jar
```